# Function goes to recursive mode on submit

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting username and password through queryparams and showing that data in input field of PHP website and using JavaScript to show dashboard instead of login page. But website goes to recursive mode when directly calling login button function, for that I am using alert to stop for 2 seconds. Is it possible to directly get that data and show dashboard.

```
echo ' Username ---> ' .$_GET['xuser_name'];
echo ' password ---> ' .$_GET['xuser_password'];

$str .= getFormRowTextInput('xuser_name', $l['w_username'], $l['h_login_name'], '', $username, '', 255, false, false, false, '');
   
$str .= getFormRowTextInput('xuser_password', $l['w_password'], $l['h_password'], '', $password, '', 255, false, false, true, '');

$str .= '<input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="'.$l['w_login'].'" title="'.$l['h_login_button'].'" />'.K_NEWLINE;
```

```
<script>

   window.onload = function(){
              
document.getElementById('login').value="anuj";
  
    document.getElementById("login").onclick = async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = document.getElementById('login');
        await button.form.submit();
  
       var currentLocation = window.location;
       console.log("test",currentLocation.href);
         setInterval(alertFunc, 2000);
if(!(currentLocation.href.includes("logout=1"))){
     
} 
  return true;
}
document.getElementById('login').click();
 }
   
   function alertFunc() {
 alert("You are Redirected to TCEXAM")
 console.log("Clicked");
   var button = document.getElementById('login');
  button.form.submit();
 }

</script>
```

Comment: My first guess is that you want `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: What do you mean "goes to recursive mode"? How is PHP involved in your problem?

Comment: I am getting data via queryparams in php website. I just need to Autologin that particular website using those data, for which I am getting recursive issue. Recursive issue means if not used alert than it don't stops at once load... It refereshes login.php page continous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   window.onload = function(){
              
// document.getElementById('login').value="anuj";
  
    document.getElementById("login").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var currentLocation = window.location;
  console.log("test",currentLocation.href);
if(!(currentLocation.href.includes("logout=1"))){
    // console.log("test",currentLocation.href);
    // console.log("Clicked");
  var button = document.getElementById('login');
  button.form.submit();
    //  setInterval(alertFunc, 2000);
} else if(currentLocation.href.includes("logout=1")){
    //console.log("test",currentLocation.href);
//    alert("Logged Out");
}else{
    alert("Wrong Username and Password");
    console.log("Wrong Username and Password");
}

  return true;
}
document.getElementById('login').click();
 }
```